# remove tags <a> to a specific URL domain php

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

This is a script code that is not mine, I try to modify it. What it does search for all the   tags and then delete them. How would you modify the code to erase only the   tags of a given domain or url? for example, delete the domain tags: www.domainurl.com , Remove all tags as:

```
     <a href="https://www.domainurl.com/refer/google-adsense/">fsdf</a>
    <a title="Google Adsense" href="https://www.domainurl.com/refer/google-adsense/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener">fgddf</a>
    <a href="https://www.domainurl.com/page/pago">domain </a>
<a title="Google Adsense" href="https://www.googlead.com/refer/google-adsense/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener">googled</a>
```

result would look like this:

```
fsdf
fgddf
domain
<a title="Google Adsense" href="https://www.googlead.com/refer/google-adsense/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener">google</a>
```

This is the code :

```
if (in_array ( 'OPT_STRIP', $camp_opt )) {
                          echo '<br>Striping links ';

                        //$abcont = strip_tags ( $abcont, '<p><img><b><strong><br><iframe><embed><table><del><i><div>' );


                        preg_match_all('{<a.*?>(.*?)</a>}' , $abcont , $allLinksMatchs);


                        $allLinksTexts    = $allLinksMatchs[1];
                        $allLinksMatchs=$allLinksMatchs[0];


                        $j = 0;
                        foreach ($allLinksMatchs as $singleLink){

                            if(! stristr($singleLink, 'twitter.com'))
                            $abcont = str_replace($singleLink, $allLinksTexts[$j], $abcont);

                            $j++;
                        }
}
```

I tried doing this but it did not work for me:

Regex :

Specifying in the search with preg_match_all

```
 preg_match_all('{<a.*?[^>]* href="((https?:\/\/)?([\w\-])+\.{1}domainurl\.([a-z]{2,6})([\/\w\.-]*)*\/?)">(.*?)</a>}' , $abcont , $allLinksMatchs);
```

Any ideas? , I would thank you a lot

Comment: So are you receiving a list of <a> elements, one per line? Or are those <a> elements embedded in some HTML code with other elements as well?

Comment: I can't stress enough ([and nor can this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3578036)) how bad parsing HTML with RegEx is... Consider [using an XML/HTML parser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55009158/3578036)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than try and [parse HTML with regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3578036), as you suggested, I have chosen to use the DOMDocument class instead.

```
function remove_domain($str, $domainsToRemove)
{
    $domainsToRemove = is_array($domainsToRemove) ? $domainsToRemove : array_slice(func_get_args(), 1);

    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML("<div>{$str}</div>", LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

    $anchors = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
    // Code taken and modified from: http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.replacechild.php#50500
    $i = $anchors->length - 1;
    while ($i > -1) {
        $anchor = $anchors->item($i);

        foreach ($domainsToRemove as $domain) {
            if (strpos($anchor->getAttribute('href'), $domain) !== false) {
                // $new = $dom->createElement('p', $anchor->textContent);
                $new = $dom->createTextNode($anchor->textContent);

                $anchor->parentNode->replaceChild($new, $anchor);
            }
        }

        $i--;
    }

    // Create HTML string, then remove the wrapping div.
    $html = $dom->saveHTML();
    $html = substr($html, 5, strlen($html) - (strlen('</div>') + 1) - strlen('<div>'));

    return $html;
}
```

You can then use the above code in the following examples.
Notice how you can either pass in a string as a domain to remove, or you can pass an array of domains, or you can take advantage of `func_get_args` and pass in an infinite number of parameters.

```
$str = <<<str
     <a href="https://www.domainurl.com/refer/google-adsense/">fsdf</a>
    <a title="Google Adsense" href="https://www.domainurl.com/refer/google-adsense/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener">fgddf</a>
    <a href="https://www.domainurl.com/page/pago">domain </a>
<a title="Google Adsense" href="https://www.googlead.com/refer/google-adsense/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener">googled</a>
str;

// Example usage
remove_domain($str, 'domainurl.com');
remove_domain($str, 'domainurl.com', 'googlead.com');
remove_domain($str, ['domainurl.com', 'googlead.com']);
```

Firstly, I have stored your string in a variable, but that is just so that I could utilize it for the answer; replace `$str` with wherever you get that code from.

The [`loadHTML`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) function takes an HTML string, but requires one child element - hence why I have wrapped the string in a div.

The while loop will iterate over the anchor elements, and then replace any that match a specified domain with just the content of the anchor tags.
Note, I have left in a comment above this line which you can use instead. This will replace the anchor element with a `p` tag, which will have a default style of `display: block;` meaning that your layout won't be likely to break. However, since your expected output is just text nodes, I have left this as just an option.

[Live demo](https://3v4l.org/aUt7X)

Comment: Some idea to put several domains and not just one : $domainToRemove = 'domainurl.com',google.com','domainxd.com';  So would it be correct?

Comment: @juan I have updated the answer so that now you can remove multiple URLs.

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
<a.*? href=\".*www\.googlead\.com.*\">(.*?)<\/a>
```

So it becomes:

```
preg_match_all('{<a.*? href=\".*www\.googlead\.com.*\">(.*?)<\/a>}' , $abcont , $allLinksMatchs);
```

This removes only `a` tags from `www.googlead.com`.

You can check the regex result [here](https://regex101.com/r/bbedRf/1).

Comment: Well mine was just an example, he can replace it with `www.domainurl.com`. He doesn't want to keep it, he does want to delete every tags coming from a specific domain.

Comment: If badly formed HTML is passed to this regular expression then it will get matched with this pattern. For instance `<a> href="www.googlead.com"><span>some more stuff</span></a>` would successfully match on your expression.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your HTML is contained in a variable for the following.

The usage of [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-replace.php) should be a better option, here's a function that should help you a bit:

```php
function removeLinkTagsOfDomain($html, $domain) {
    // Escape all regex special characters
    $domain = preg_quote($domain);

    // Search for <a> tags with a href attribute containing the specified domain
    $pattern = '/<a .*href=".*' . $domain . '.*".*>(.+)<\/a>/';

    // Final replacement (should be the text node of <a> tags)
    $replacer = '$1';

    return preg_replace($pattern, '$1', $html);
}

// Usage:

$domains = [...];
$html = '...';

foreach ($domains as $d) {
    $html = removeLinkTagsOfDomain($html, $d);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it with multiple `<a>` tags in the same line? Or, if a single `<a>` tag is exploded on multiple lines?